# Git: local branch lost remote after a merge

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am working on a feature branch "feature/myFeature" that is tracking a remote branch "origin/feature/myFeature"

I recently merged from develop into myFeature, because I needed to integrate another developer's bug fix to keep working.  (we are using gitflow, so my feature branch was originally branched from develop)

Somehow after the merge, my local branch no longer tracks the remote for git push.  I want to make sure that I don't lose anything. Any idea how to fix it.

Here's the output from git remote show origin

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://urltomyrepo
  Push  URL: http://urltomyrepo
  HEAD branch: develop
  Remote branches:
    develop                                              tracked
    feature/myFeature (fake name)                        tracked
    master                                               tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop          merges with remote develop
    feature/myFeature  merges with remote feature/myFeature
    master           merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop          pushes to develop          (up to date)
    master           pushes to master           (up to date)
```

Notice that feature/myFeature shows up as configured for git pull, but not for git push.  Any idea how to fix this?

If it helps at all, the merge was performed using the integration built into Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Comment: You might want to add the output of `git config --list`, or at the very least, `git config --get push.default` and `git config --get-all remote.origin.push` (these two will be included in the `--list` output). Depending on what if anything is in `push.default` and/or `remote.origin.push`, *and* on your Git version, the result next depends on what's in each branch's configuration (which will also be in `git config --list` output). Note that I know nothing about Visual Studio (that include what version(s) of Git it may embed).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
git push origin feature/myFeature
```

It will just push your local commits to origin. So it should track origin after it.

Advice : Use GIT in command line.

Comment: Hi Matthieu.  No go on that:  git push origin feature/myFeature responded with: fatal: feature/myFeature cannot be resolved to a branch.  However, the pull works:  pull origin feature/myFeature responds with already up-to-date.

Comment: Then let's see how are your pointers... could you provide the result of this command : git log --graph --oneline --all --pretty=format:'%h -%d %s'

Comment: Hm, if `feature/myFeature cannot be resolved to a branch`, it sounds like the local branch name has been deleted entirely. Meanwhile the `git remote show` output implies that the configuration *entry* for the branch still exists. Note that deleting a branch *name* does not immediately delete its commits: they may (or may not) become unprotected and hence vulnerable to deletion, but they aren't immediately removed.

Comment: Haven't you mispelled your branch name ? On your example, you put a fake name but you might have copied / pasted the same name everywhere whereas the branch names are differents.